# Tengo una tabla dinámica, la ultima fila es para agregar y las anteriores para modificar. estoy utilizando javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buen dia, hace unos dias e detectado que tengo un problema con el funcionamiento de una tabla dinámica que cuenta con 5 columnas(btn, input1,input2,input3,input4), la cual tiene muchas funciones la cual requiero es de dos, agregar en la ultima fila, y modificar en las filas anteriores.

Modo nuevo: por efecto se muestra una fila por defecto para poder llenar los campos(input1,input2,input3,input4).

Agregar:

*cuando estoy en la fila1(pordefecto)-columna4(input4) al dar enter lo que hace es agregar una nueva fila debajo.

*nueva filanueva-columna4(input4) al dar enter lo que hace es agregar una nueva fila debajo.

*Asi sucesivamente.

Modificar:

*Esto pasa con las filas que ya se registraron, las anteriores que la fila nueva, hace el modificado en la cualquier fila (anteriores de la nueva dila agregada) en columna(input4) al dar enter.

Esto funciona ok, pero me doy cuenta que en el DevTools que en esta haciendo las dos funciones ajax al momento de agregar en la fila por defecto, y lo que se requiere es solo agregar.

En las filas anteriores para modificar, solo modica eso esta bien.

[Tabla fila por defecto para poder agregar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPDW6.png)

[Ejemplo fila anterior, fila nueva, asi sucesivamente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe5My.png)

Código que utilizo para detectar las filas: columna=>input4(.infotab_pruc)

Filas anteriores

```
$("#tabla_ingresoinfo").on('keypress','tr .infotab_pruc',function(e) {...});
```

Fila nueva

```
("#tabla_ingresoinfo").on('keypress','tr:last-child .infotab_pruc',function(e) {...});
```

Bueno, espero a ver explicado detalladamente, me pueden ayudar a solucionar este problema. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega código que nos permita reproducir tu problema para poder tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: Como hago para poner la fila por defecto  al inicio de la tabla ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el ultimo elemento tal como lo tienes cumple con ambos selectores por eso se ejecuta 2 veces.

Una opción para evitar eso seria utilizar `:not`, de modo que

```
$("#tabla_ingresoinfo").on('keypress','tr .infotab_pruc',function(e) {...});
```

quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
("#tabla_ingresoinfo").on('keypress','tr .infotab_pruc:not(tr:last-child .infotab_pruc)',function(e) {...});
```

así se toma en cuenta los `tr` con la la clase `infotab_pruc` excepto el ultimo elemento (que ejecutaría el otro selector que tienes).

Comment: muchas gracias, primero no me funciono pero pude ver que solo era dar espacio después del tr `tr .infotab_pruc:not(tr:last-child .infotab_pruc)` y listo, muchas gracias.